# autoresize mask is making width of view to 0

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, autoresizingmask

In the following code I see that if I just set the autoresize mask of the `redView` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` the width of the view is made 0 after I rotate the screen.

But If I make it `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`, the behavior is as expected, the view width and height are scaled in proportion to width and height of new screen.

Why isn't just setting flexibleHeight and width not enough?

```
UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 150)];
redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

//This makes the width 0 after rotation
//redView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

//This works
redView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

[self.view addSubview:redView];
```

Comment: What's the width of `self.view` before and after the rotation?

Comment: @dan 320*568 before and 568*320 after.